# Disable "Login with the Facebook app" button on facebook login for ios

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login

Is there any way to disable/hide the "Login with the Facebook app" button on facebook login for ios?

I'm currently using the current fb-sdk version

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't think you can/should be able to do that. You'd better hide/disable your instance of FBLoginButton in the first place.